# Can the internal part of a slip-on tub spout be removed to install it as a front-end threaded spout?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, bathtub, spout

I bought a Pfister pfirst modern shower trim kit as it's one of the few compatible with my 80's Pfister Avante valve.

I'm discovering now, however, that the included tub spout appears to be the "slip on" style, while the old spout I'd like to replace is the front-end threaded kind that screws on to the threaded pipe.

Looking into the new spot, it seems like the internal slip on component is itself threaded into the front end of the spout and could possibly be just as well unscrewed, however I've been unable to do so with light pressure and don't want to force and break it since it if doesn't work I'll likely return this.

I wanted to ask if anyone has had experience successfully doing this!  I guess my other option is to cut the pipe?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's a soldered threaded fitting on copper pipe:

Place a rag-class towel or other large rag in the bottom of the tub.

Take a torch, heat until the solder melts, yank the fitting off (use thick gloves or pliers) quickly wipe molten solder clean with a rag before it cools and hardens.

Answer (score 1):

You could return it  for the correct one.

> I guess my other option is to cut the pipe?

Clean off the pipe with emery cloth, cut the threaded male fitting off  and deburr  the end of the pipe so you do not damage the O ring in the spout.

Now you have pipe you can slip the spout onto.

I do not think trying to remove the threaded part of the spout is a good idea but if you can afford another one if it breaks then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Funny I just mentioned doing just this to another person that had the screw on and wondered what the slot was for.
I know they used to come apart fairly easily but that was 35 years ago. Most of the slip on’s are for copper so cut the pipe and slip it on.

I would cut it long slip on and get an exact measurement.
Then cut that amount off, there is usually some room for extra pipe length.
Just don’t cut it off two short.